# Use numbers stored in a command by spreadtab

Tags: tables, calculations, xstring, spreadtab

My aim is to create a command to store numbers and calculated in the table.

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \npthousandsep{,}
  \STautoround*{0}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{| l | r | r | r |}} \hline
                        & @\textbf{Current Arrangement} & @\textbf{New Arrangement} & @\textbf{Difference} \\ \hline
    @Base Salary (SGD)  & 50000.00                      & 60000.00                  & c2-b2\\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}
\end{table}
```

But for some reason, I have to load the number from the code. For example, I use `\newcommand{\BASESALARYAMOUNT}{50,000.00}` to replace part of the table. Because of the existence of `,`, I use `xstring` to delete it by the following command. But it does not run.

```
\newcommand{\BASESALARYAMOUNT}{50,000.00}
\newcommand{\basesalaryamountno}{\StrSubstitute{\BASESALARYAMOUNT{}}{,}{}}
\begin{table}[h]
  \npthousandsep{,}
  \STautoround*{0}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{| l | r | r | r |}} \hline
                        & @\textbf{Current Arrangement} & @\textbf{New Arrangement} & @\textbf{Difference} \\ \hline
    @Base Salary (SGD)  & \BASESALARYAMOUNT             & 60000.00                  & c2-b2\\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}
\end{table}
```

Any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach with `stringstrings`, if I understand the OP's problem.  The macro `\convertchar[q]{\BASESALARYAMOUNT}{,}{}` removes the comma character from `\BASESALARYAMOUNT` and stores the result in `\thestring` for later recall.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab,numprint,stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\BASESALARYAMOUNT}{50,000.00}
\convertchar[q]{\BASESALARYAMOUNT}{,}{}
\begin{table}[h]
  \npthousandsep{,}
  \STautoround*{0}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{| l | r | r | r |}} \hline
                        & @\textbf{Current Arrangement} & @\textbf{New Arrangement} & @\textbf{Difference} \\ \hline
    @Base Salary (SGD)  & \thestring            & 60000.00                  & c2-b2\\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. Do you know what's the reason that `xstring` does not work here?

Comment: @Joe I am not an `xstring` user, but I've seen enough questions involving it to suspect that the problem is that the operation needs to be "fully expandable".  I know that `xstring` provides some tricks to do this, but I have no real familiarity with them.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `\newcommand{\basesalaryamountno}{\StrSubstitute{\BASESALARYAMOUNT{}}{,}{}}`, I found `\StrDel{\BASESALARYAMOUNT{}}{,}[\baseamount]` can solve the problem. This could delete the `,` in the numbers and store the new string in the `\baseamount`.